# Why chrome sets cookie on wrong subdomain?

Tags: python, google-chrome, nginx, cookies, flask

I have following subdomains:

```
api.example.com
app1.example.com
app2.example.com
```

I am using nginx as web server to serve all of those. `api.example.com` is python-flask application which I am developing. `app1.example.com` and `app2.example.com` are static js content, not developed by me.

Nginx is configured to allow cross-origin resource sharing:

```
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000 always;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' always;
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0 always;
            return 204;
    }
    if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
    }
    if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,Authorization' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
    }
```

Above lands at `location` block, which passes control to uwsgi socket. Same is copy-pasted for `api1` and `api2`.

`app1` and `app2` are making requests to the `api`, and `api` sets cookie on response to some of those requests.

Cookies are set like this:

```
response.set_cookie(
        key='some_cookie_name',
        value=some_token,
        max_age=current_app.config["JWT_EXP"],
        secure=True,
        httponly=True)
```

`path` is by default set to `'/'`,
`domain` attribute is not present in response,
`samesite` attribute is not present as well,
all above according to [this documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Response.set_cookie).

Correct me if I am wrong, but according to my understanding, when `app1` requests an `api` resource (which is setting cookie), this cookie is bounded to `app1.example.com` and should not be present on `app2.example.com` (and vice versa).

Behaviour which I am observing on chrome is differernt.

Setting cookie on `app1` request, and then setting cookie (with the same name) on `app2` request, overrides cookie on `app1`. `app2` subdomain have no cookies present (inspecting with chrome developer tools).

Now, when I change the name of the cookie for the second subdomain (`app2`), cookies still will not be present on `app2`, however, second cookie with different name is now visible on `app1` subdomain.

It looks like whatever I do, all cookies are set on `app1` subdomain. Those cookies are also present when inspecting `example.com`.

Moreover, when `app2.example.com` makes request to the `api` its sends back all cookies visible on `app1`.

Is this behaviour correct? Does it due to CORS enabled on server side? How can I separate cookies between `app1` and `app2`?

*edit: added cors configuration code*

Comment: can you show me your CORS implementation? In my opinion, you have got CORS problem.

Comment: I've added nginx cors configuration to the question.

Comment: Can you show me the response headers from this:
`curl -X OPTIONS 'api.example.com' -H "Origin: app1.example.com" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" -Iv -o /dev/null`
It looks, like your CORS implementation is fine.

Comment: Here is an output. Ofc I've requested proper resource as proper origin, changed it to `app1` when posting: https://pastebin.com/raw/nUuJAmZE

Comment: IN, my oppinion something is wrong in your application, because your CORS implementation is correct(but not safe). You received valid headers on above request.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie domain in the set-cookie header needs to match the host that it was requested from. Both the CORS and cookie headers are needed. If you don't set a domain on a Set-Cookie, the browser will assume the FQDN of the requested host. If you do set a domain, you can share the cookie between sites on the same domain by using domain=example.com or similar.

It is possible, though confusing, to have the same cookie name set on the FQDN host and on the domain the host is in. One will get sent to other hosts in that domain, and *both* will get sent to subsequent calls to the same FQDN.

I expect you want the cookie on your domain, and not on the FQDN. You should be able to rewrite the Set-Cookie header returned by apt, app1 and app2 so that they are on the domain instead. Better to fix the cookies on the applications themselves if possible.

Comment: Alas, if I could have commented instead of answered, I would have. But one gets rights to answer before getting rights to comment.